# Is the sentence " We are more or less the same age." Syntactically correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntax

We are more or less the same age.

We are more or less **of** same age.

Which one is correct, and a how a Noun describe someone,( I can't say **They are blackness, I am humbleness** etc.but how I can say like this( We are more or less **the same age**.))

Comment: Why do you think a noun can't describe someone?  "I am a businessman", for example.  "I am humbleness" doesn't make sense because *humbleness* is an abstract quality, not because the grammar is wrong.

Comment: The first is correct. The second is wrong.

Comment: @stangdon in your example the noun "businessman" reidentifies the subject(I) but in my example the noun is different.

Comment: @Sam That seems more like a philosophical question about what *is* and identity mean than a linguistic question.

Comment: Voting to close, as asking "is this correct" is off-topic. There is a definition of 'more or less' in the dictionary which also contains examples. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/more-or-less

Comment: @Astralbee i have asked it from grammar point of view, it's a question related to syntax.

Comment: @sam But there is no research. You are just asking "is this correct"? The site rules outline that this would be considered proofreading, and off-topic. Your question needs to be on a point of grammar, so that we can answer it from a grammatical point of view, and so that future learners with the same question as you can search for it and find the answer. There is no question of grammar here, only "here's some writing, is it correct".

Comment: @Astralbee my question is about correct usage of Noun and adjective, I also have given so many examples that  confused me that's my research.

Comment: You say "we are the same height", "we are the same religion", and many other things. If that's what you're asking about, which isn't clear as you don't say what you're actually asking, then it's nothing strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“We are more or less the same age” is perfectly acceptable English. Does it parse per some simple grammar? No. Does that matter? No.

Compare….

1. “What weight are you?”
2. “What religion are you?”
3. “What nationality are you?”

They’re all completely natural English-language utterances. And they all fit a pattern according to which an *of* is dropped: “of more or less the same age,” “Of what nationality,” etc.

Natural languages cannot be legislated. They are whatever their speakers make them.

Answer (score 0):

The first is correct. The second is not.

"More or less the same age" is not a noun. The elementary definition of a noun is "a person, place, or thing" and this isn't that. "The same age" is equivalent to "just as old".

"Age" is a noun and you could not say "we are age" (except maybe in a very abstract, poetic, metaphorical way).

Comment: I want to know the grammar behind this. Why they are equivalent?